# How does Create React App allow for Array.prototype.at() while it's not allowed by TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, tsconfig

In our CRA project we have a code like this:

```
const patTable = tables['pat'].at(0);
```

The `Array.prototype.at()` function is a new one and not available in the older browsers (e.g. Chrome 89). But for some reason CRA didn't message even a warning or error and easily accepted it. It didn't also polyfill the `.at()` function and now it's breaking the app in the older browsers.

The inferred type displayed by WebStorm is `Table | undefined` (due to @types/node 16.x, but I'm not sure).

Also note that TypeScript doesn't support `.at()` yet, e.g:

```
function foo(values: string[]) {
  const value = values.at(0);
}
```

raises an error: `Property 'at' does not exist on type 'string[]'.(2339)`

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUA3AhgGxAUwGcAuRQqAJxjAHMBtAXQEpEBvAKEUQgXMWzz5EAXn64ChAHRYoaAAxMA3OwC%207IA)

Do you have any ideas how is it possible that neither TS-checking, nor linting or building have detected the problem?

The TS version is: 4.3.5
`tsconfig.json` is:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "types/global-fetch.d.ts"]
}
```

Comment: `"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],` notice the `esnext`

Comment: Nah, it doesn't affect it. The only line which affected by `esnext` in our project was `someString.replaceAll(...)`. 100%.

Comment: @Onkeltem - Even though it doesn't *now*, it will, so you need to consider whether that `"esnext"` is really appropriate for the project.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, I see. Yeah, I would rather attach some specific polyfills. E.g.: for my `replaceAll()` only.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably picking it up from the Node.js types even though you're dealing with browser-targeted code. Node.js's types include `RelativeIndexable` — from `@types/node/globals.d.ts`:

```typescript
//#region ArrayLike.at()
interface RelativeIndexable<T> {
    /**
     * Takes an integer value and returns the item at that index,
     * allowing for positive and negative integers.
     * Negative integers count back from the last item in the array.
     */
    at(index: number): T | undefined;
}
interface String extends RelativeIndexable<string> {}
interface Array<T> extends RelativeIndexable<T> {}
interface Int8Array extends RelativeIndexable<number> {}
interface Uint8Array extends RelativeIndexable<number> {}
interface Uint8ClampedArray extends RelativeIndexable<number> {}
interface Int16Array extends RelativeIndexable<number> {}
interface Uint16Array extends RelativeIndexable<number> {}
interface Int32Array extends RelativeIndexable<number> {}
interface Uint32Array extends RelativeIndexable<number> {}
interface Float32Array extends RelativeIndexable<number> {}
interface Float64Array extends RelativeIndexable<number> {}
interface BigInt64Array extends RelativeIndexable<bigint> {}
interface BigUint64Array extends RelativeIndexable<bigint> {}
//#endregion ArrayLike.at() end
```

I've had this issue with Node.js types being picked up in projects that are built using Node even though they're building for browsers. (I mostly run into it on the return value of `setTimeout`.) I just checked a project, and sure enough, it was happy to use `at` (and resolves it to the above) even though I hadn't ever explicitly installed `@types/node` in the project.

I don't use WebStorm, but in VSCode you'd be able to check where the type for `at` is coming from by putting your cursor on the `at` and pressing F12 for "Go to definition." Presumably WebStorm has sometinng similar.

I think this is useful information, and more appropriate to an answer than a comment, but it does sort of beg the question "So how do I prevent that?" which I have to admit I can't answer right now. I've marked the answer CW, hopefully someone can update to address it.

Comment: Thank you anyway! I confirm that I have exactly the same typedefs under `node_modules/@types/node` - i.e. node (v.16). IDEs seem to behave similarly - WS consumes the types from there too. I cannot answer however how CRA's webpack "magically" consumes this `.at()`. It looks like there were a temporary polyfill which is engaged while typechecking and put aside afterwards while building (and thus getting into the built app untouched).

Comment: That code isn't run during the build, right? It's client-side code. So no temporary polyfill or anything, just the `@types/node` types making TypeScript think `at` will be there at runtime when it won't (necessarily) be.

Comment: Phew, how intricate it is. And those node 16 types came unexpectedly via dependencies. Then it's definitely worth disabling this automatic types... acquisition. I hoped I could do this using `"exclude": ["node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts"]` in `tsconfig.json` but... nah. It's not the way. After all why would one want to include the **node** types while building a browser app?